# Where is the right place to add the user and time a command was issued in NServiceBus?

Tags: nservicebus

Some of my NServiceBus commands will need to track who issued the command and when.  I'm very unsure as to the recommended way to implement this:

Should I create a base class `MessageBase`, add `public Dictionary<string, string> Headers;`, and implement `IMutateOutgoingMessages`?

Should it be added to the MessageContext?  If so, how do I ensure the Bus adds it before every message (which needs the headers) is sent?

Is it already done and I just don't know how to access it?  (It looks like the user is in the raw MSMQ message...)

Comment: I would probably add this type of information to the message header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NServiceBus already gives you the time the message was sent using the "NServiceBus.TimeSent" header.

Use the builtin NServiceBus headers dictionary and skip the MessageBase

Attaching user id is best done in a outgoing message mutator. Just grab the ID from eg the HttpContext and add it as a header.

http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/860492

To get the time (in your handler/saga):

`Bus.CurrentMessageContext.TimeSent`

Comment: By "builtin NServiceBus headers" do you mean the ones in MessageContext?

Comment: Ahh, I understand now - there's some magic that goes on behind the scenes via extension methods so that you don't need to put headers in the messages themselves.  My confusion was because I was running a simple unit test and didn't have a Get/SetHeader method defined and didn't understand how it works against a real Bus.